# Vitest - ReferenceError: File Is Not Defined

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite, vitest

I'm usually able to use `File` wherever I want to in my code, but for some reason when I try using it in vitest it throws this error. Why does this happen and how can I resolve this error?

Here is my `vite.config.ts`

```
/// <reference types="vitest" />
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// Configure Vitest (https://vitest.dev/config/)
export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    /* for example, use global to avoid globals imports (describe, test, expect): */
    // globals: true,
  },
  plugins: [vue()],
})
```

And here is my test file code.

```
import { assert, expect, test } from 'vitest'

test('File', () => {
  let applicationZip = new File(new Array<Blob>(), "Mock.zip", { type: 'application/zip' })
})
```

Whenever I run vitest it throws the following error.

```
ReferenceError: File is not defined
 ❯ test/basic.test.ts:25:23
     23| 
     24| test('File', () => {
     25|   let applicationZip = new File(new Array<Blob>(), "Mock.zip", { type: 'application/zip' })
       |                       ^
     26| })
     27|
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered through [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48237766/file-is-not-defined-error-in-javascript-while-executing-from-node-js-command-p) that `File` isn't in nodejs but instead provided by the browser's DOM, thus explains the error from vitest since it's pure node. Through some more thorough reading of vitest's docs I learned that vitest can be configured with an environment like jsdom which will provide the `File` object I need in my test. After modifying my `vite.config.ts` with the following environment setting that error no longer showed up.

```
/// <reference types="vitest" />
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: "jsdom",
  },
  root: ".",
})
```

Comment: Thanks! For React with typescript, I had to put test section in a separate vitest.config.ts as described here: https://vitest.dev/config/. BR