# What is the correct way to provide a File object to the OpenAI Whisper API in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, typescript, openai-api

Suppose I want to download a file from a URL and then call the whisper API to transcribe it.

I would do it as the [documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/audio/create?lang=node) suggests:

> ```
> const resp = await openai.createTranscription(
>   fs.createReadStream("audio.mp3"),
>   "whisper-1"
> );
> ```

in my implementation:

```js
public static async transcribeFromPublicUrl({ url, format }: { url: string; format: string }) {
    const now = new Date().toISOString();
    const filePath = `${this.tmpdir}/${now}.${format}`;
    try {
      const response = await axios.get<Stream>(url, {
        responseType: 'stream',
      });
      const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
      response.data.pipe(fileStream);

      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fileStream.on('finish', resolve);
        fileStream.on('error', reject);
      });

      const transcriptionResponse = await 
      this.openai.createTranscription(fs.readFileSync(filePath), 'whisper');
      return { success: true, response: transcriptionResponse };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to download the file:', error);
      return { success: false, error: error };
    }
  }
```

However this poses the following error:

```
Argument of type 'Buffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'File'.
  Type 'Buffer' is missing the following properties from type 'File': lastModified, name, webkitRelativePath, size, and 5 more.ts(2345)
```

Okay, no biggie, let's convert the Buffer to a File:

```js
...
 const file = new File([fs.readFileSync(filePath)], now, { type: `audio/${format}` });
 const transcriptionResponse = await this.openai.createTranscription(file, 'whisper');
...
```

Although this does not throw any typescript errors, but the [javascript File api is not available from node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48237766/file-is-not-defined-error-in-javascript-while-executing-from-node-js-command-p)

Looking more into it, I see that the openai library requires a File type to be passed as an argument:

> ```js
> /**
>      *
>      * @summary Transcribes audio into the input language.
>      * @param {File} file The audio file to transcribe, in one of these formats: mp3, mp4, mpeg, mpga, m4a, wav, or webm.
>      * @param {string} model ID of the model to use. Only &#x60;whisper-1&#x60; is currently available.
>      * @param {string} [prompt] An optional text to guide the model\\\&#39;s style or continue a previous audio segment. The [prompt](/docs/guides/speech-to-text/prompting) should match the audio language.
>      * @param {string} [responseFormat] The format of the transcript output, in one of these options: json, text, srt, verbose_json, or vtt.
>      * @param {number} [temperature] The sampling temperature, between 0 and 1. Higher values like 0.8 will make the output more random, while lower values like 0.2 will make it more focused and deterministic. If set to 0, the model will use [log probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_probability) to automatically increase the temperature until certain thresholds are hit.
>      * @param {string} [language] The language of the input audio. Supplying the input language in [ISO-639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) format will improve accuracy and latency.
>      * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
>      * @throws {RequiredError}
>      * @memberof OpenAIApi
> */
> createTranscription(file: File, model: string, prompt?: string, responseFormat?: string, temperature?: number, language?: string, options?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<import("axios").AxiosResponse<CreateTranscriptionResponse, any>>;
> ```

So to recap: I don't have access to the File API on NodeJs, yet I am supposed to provide a File for the openai library?

Comment: have you tried something in the lines of using a [web-file-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-file-polyfill)

Comment: I have, but without luck, most of them ran into issues down the line, web-file-polyfill doesn't implement the 'source-on' method as an example `TypeError: source.on is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

I doesn't seem that `createTranscription` is being invoked in line with the example from the [docs](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/audio/create?lang=node). Compare:

`createTranscription(fs.readFileSync(filePath), 'whisper');`

vs.

`createTranscription(fs.createReadStream("audio.mp3"), "whisper-1")`

Adjusting the following line should do the trick (at least it worked for me today):

```
const transcriptionResponse = await this.openai.createTranscription(
  fs.readFileSync(filePath),
  'whisper'
);
```

=>

```
const transcriptionResponse = await this.openai.createTranscription(
  fs.createReadStream(filePath),
  'whisper-1'
);
```

For some reason this works, even though `fs.createReadStream` method returns `fs.ReadStream` class.

Note model name correction as well.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this trick. Adding `name` and `lastModified` worked at the end.

```js
    const file = new Blob([content], {
      type: 'application/octet-stream',
    }) as any;
    file.name = 'audio.wav';
    file.lastModified = Date.now();

    const transcription = await this.openai.audio.transcriptions.create({
      file,
      model: 'whisper-1',
      language: 'en',
    });
```